# Android, network request, cancel within onStop but keep on rotation

Tags: android, retrofit, activity-lifecycle

I have a Login Activity. User sends request with email and password to login.
I'm using Retrofit 2, and there is new functionality to cancel request. (This is not really matter, question is more general).

If user presses back - I want to cancel request. But if user rotate phone - I want request to proceed.
So I can't call canceling within onStop.
Of course I can cancel request on Back pressed. But I think there are more cases, when Activity stopped.

Another way I see is to use `android:configChanges="orientation"`.

I'll be thankful for any ideas and "best practices".

Comment: @Androider fixed orientation is bad

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a Fragment without any UI in your Activity's onCreate() and start your networking in that Fragment's onCreate, starting AsyncTask.

And in this Fragment's onCreate you do setRetainIntance(true) this way the Fragment doesn't get destroyed when your Activity changes orientation.

And you inform in AsyncTask onPostExecute using getActivity()

See here, perfect example: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: What will happen to request if user presses Back?

Comment: Activity then gets destroyed and thus your Fragment too and so networking will be stopped too (you cancel your AsyncTask in your Fragment's onDestroy). No need to override onBackPressed

Comment: In this case I could simply cancel request on activity destroy.
But documentation says that there is no guaranty that onDestroy will be called.

Comment: If you press back then the defaul onBackPressed calls finish() which results in onDestroy get called. If you change orientation onDestroy gets called as well but the fragment remains since it's set to retain